# How to inject a dynamic feature to a module in android?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, inject, dynamic-feature

I'm new to android and now I'm currently working on a project which asks me to split some dynamic features from an Android app.

I followed the guide on the Internet, but when I try to run my code, it shows the following error message:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/io.github.hidroh.materialistic.module.JobsActivity. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
```

I split jobboard as my dynamic feature, here's the source code.

```java
package io.github.hidroh.materialistic.module;
import dagger.*;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import io.github.hidroh.materialistic.BaseStoriesActivity;
import io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.ItemManager;
public class JobsActivity extends BaseStoriesActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getDefaultTitle() {
        return "Jobs";
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getFetchMode() {
        return ItemManager.JOBS_FETCH_MODE;
    }

}
```

And I also find the place which needs to inject my code which is based on dagger2(I'm also new to this package):

```java
@Module(
        injects = {
                AboutActivity.class,
                AskActivity.class,
                BestActivity.class,
                ComposeActivity.class,
                FavoriteActivity.class,
                FeedbackActivity.class,
                ItemActivity.class,
                JobsActivity.class,
                ListActivity.class,
                LoginActivity.class,
                BaseStoriesActivity.class,
                NewActivity.class,
                OfflineWebActivity.class,
                PopularActivity.class,
                ReleaseNotesActivity.class,
                SearchActivity.class,
                SettingsActivity.class,
                ShowActivity.class,
                SubmitActivity.class,
                ThreadPreviewActivity.class,
                UserActivity.class,
                WidgetConfigActivity.class,
                FavoriteFragment.class,
                ItemFragment.class,
                ListFragment.class,
                WebFragment.class,
                FavoriteRecyclerViewAdapter.class,
                SinglePageItemRecyclerViewAdapter.class,
                StoryRecyclerViewAdapter.class,
                SubmissionRecyclerViewAdapter.class,
                MultiPageItemRecyclerViewAdapter.class,
                ThreadPreviewRecyclerViewAdapter.class
        },
        library = true,
        complete = false
)
class UiModule {
    @Provides
    public PopupMenu providePopupMenu() {
        return new PopupMenu.Impl();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public CustomTabsDelegate provideCustomTabsDelegate() {
        return new CustomTabsDelegate();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public KeyDelegate provideKeyDelegate() {
        return new KeyDelegate();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public ActionViewResolver provideActionViewResolver() {
        return new ActionViewResolver();
    }

    @Provides
    public AlertDialogBuilder provideAlertDialogBuilder() {
        return new AlertDialogBuilder.Impl();
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    @Provides @Singleton
    public ResourcesProvider provideResourcesProvider(Context context) {
        return resId -> context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(resId);
    }
}
```

As all the classes are written statically in code, Is that possible to inject my job activity class dynamically to previous code when I try to load my dynamic feature?

Here below is the code try to load the dynamic feature:

```java
findViewById(R.id.drawer_job).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("io.github.hidroh.materialistic", "io.github.hidroh.materialistic.module.JobsActivity");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

If you want to view the whole project to get what I say, please visit: https://github.com/Earthaa/materialistic